# Jmeter is throwing an error Illegal character in query

Tags: jmeter

My http query

```
http://testemu.foo.com:5050/reportGroup?customerId=4&token=18817614-b662-41f1-b9e7-99a5afcf312d&searchKey={"brandId":1,"sourceType":"E-Commerce","startDate":"01/01/2017","endDate":"31/12/2017"}
```

Jmeter is throwing error

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 109

Answer (score 2):

As per [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters `"$-_.+!*'(),"`, and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

So you need to wrap your query into [__urlEncode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like:

```
${__urlencode(reportGroup?customerId=4&token=18817614-b662-41f1-b9e7-99a5afcf312d&searchKey={"brandId":1,"sourceType":"E-Commerce","startDate":"01/01/2017","endDate":"31/12/2017"})}
```

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) concept.

Comment: Still  Jmeter is throwing the same error ava.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://example.com /${__urlencode(reportGroup?customerId=4&token=18817614-b662-41f1-b9e7-99a5afcf312d&searchKey={"brandId":1,"sourceType":"E-Commerce","startDate":"01/01/2017","endDate":"31/12/2017"})}
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)

Answer (score 0):

This error is presented by the java version with which Jmeter is being used, the latest versions have this problem. It works for me with the java version "1.8.0_201" - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)